# Struct sockaddr, sin_family is not a member

Tags: windows, sockets, visual-c++

According to this article from msdn (
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) the struct varies depending on which protocol is selected!

Now I want to use this code from http://www.intelliproject.net/articles/showArticle/index/check_tcp_udp_port to check if a port is open or not!

Now I have the struct sockaddr as follows:

```
struct sockaddr {
    ushort  sa_family;
    char    sa_data[14];
};
```

but need this strcuture:

```
struct sockaddr {
    short   sin_family;
    u_short sin_port;
    struct  in_addr sin_addr;
    char    sin_zero[8];
};
```

Which changes are necessary?

(Ws2_32.lib is linked and following includes

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

// sockets
#include "windows.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
```

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In sockets API the address structure to use depends on the protocol. If you are using IPv4, the structure you need is `sockaddr_in`.

The sockets API appeared long ago when `void *` wasn't in standard. Pointers to `sockaddr` are used all over the sockets functions in exactly the same way as we would use `void *` pointers. The functions expect you to pass the pointers to the structures related to protocols you use. The unpleasant thing is that you need a cast whenever you pass a pointer to your address structure, but there is nothing you can do about it.

**IPv4 example:**

```
struct sockaddr_in address;

// ...

memset( &address, 0, sizeof(address) );

address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(1100);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if ( bind( sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address) ) < 0 )
{
   //....
}
```

Comment: Thx! Looks good, but unfortunately I dont have sin_addr.s_addr (only sin_addr.S_un)! The other struct members are accessible now!

Comment: [`s_addr` is a `#define` used to access the `S_addr` member.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922011.aspx)